# With $X, Y$ vector fields and $f$ a smooth function, show that $X(gY) = (Xg)Y + gXY$

Tags: vector-fields

I know that $X = \sum_i a_i \frac \partial\partial_{x_i}$ and $Y=\sum_j b_j \frac \partial\partial_{x_j}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed. The only approach I can think of is something to do with the chain rule.

Comment: How do you understand $XY$?

Comment: Is $XY$ the product of the summations that I gave above?

Comment: not really... what it is $XY$ is to derivate $Y$ in direction $X$. Example: $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(v^2w\frac{\partial}{\partial w})=2vw\frac{\partial}{\partial v}+v^2w\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$

Comment: so Xg is the derivative to g in the direction X? Then what does gY mean?

Comment: $gY=\sum_j gb_j \frac \partial\partial_{x_j}$

Comment: is $gY=Yg$ then?

Comment: no! $gY$ and $Yg$ are different!!

Comment: ok I get that. Yg would be $\sum_j b_j \frac {\partial g}{\partial x_j}$ . how would you express XY in notation?

Comment: don't forget to upvote if you want :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$XY=\sum_i a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}\left(\sum_j b_j\frac {\partial}{\partial x_j}\right),$$

$$=\sum_{ij} a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}\left(b_j \frac {\partial}{\partial{x_j}}\right),$$

$$=\sum_{ij} a_i \left(\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{ \partial}{\partial{x_j}}
+b_j\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}\right),$$

$$=\sum_{ij} a_i \left(\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}+b_j\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{ \partial}{\partial{x_j}}\right),$$

$$=\sum_{ij} a_i\frac{\partial b_j}{ \partial{x_i}}\frac{ \partial}{\partial{x_j}}+\sum_{ij} a_ib_j\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{ \partial}{\partial{x_j}}.$$